# Producing sequence with while loop and basic math computation

Tags: python

```
a=1
b=1
sum=(a+b)
 for i in range(100):
print(a)
print(b)
print(sum)
```

This is my current code, but I don't know how to create a code to do continuous addition to produce a sequence in python with basic math computation. I need a+b to equal c and b+c=d and so on but I don't know how to formulate that into code.

The question: Starting with two one-digit positive integers a and b, consider the sequence in which the next number is the digit in the ones place of the sum of the previous two numbers. And that returns the length of the sequence when the last two numbers repeat the values of a and b for the first time. For example, if a = 1 and b = 1, the function should return 62.

The output of this sequence should be 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 3, 1, 4, 5, 9, 4, 3, 7, 0, ...  when a=1 and b=1. Overall, I just need major help and it would be greatly appreciated if I could get my code edited and revised to produced the output.

I tried simple math computations in python.

No, there's no error messages but I need help to get to desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to loop until the array has two elements of same value: `i[cntr] != i[cntr - 1]`

In that loop you should add to your table `i.append()` the last digit of the sum of last value and the one before that (to simplify, let's start with a starting array: `[1,1,2]`).
Convert that sum in a list of digit to get the last one: `list(map(int, str(valueToConvertInListOfDigits))`

Here you go:

```py
i=[1, 1, 2]
cntr = 2
while(i[cntr] != i[cntr - 1]):
  i.append(list(map(int, str(i[cntr] + i[cntr-1])))[-1])
  cntr+=1
  print(i)
```

Comment: Hi, do you know a much simpler way to do this? Because I have not learned it the way you have done it. Is there anyway you can show me with a while loop that contains basic math computation and outputs 62 when 1 repeats?